# Paramiko not creating log file

Tags: python, logging, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to enable logging with paramiko but for some reason, it's not creating the log. Am I doing something wrong?

```
paramiko.util.log_to_file("\\Users\\armando.lopez\\paramiko.log", level = "DEBUG")
```

I run the log to file command then create a transport object and then use the SSH client()

```
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
```